# Unbale to pass value to inner class properties in mvc 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to post a request to an API with an `userid` and a list of products

I have made a similar model pass this model to post request of API

this is my model class

```
public class Checkout
{
  public string userId { get; set; }

  public productList productlist { get; set; }

  public class productList
  {
    public int productId { get; set; }

    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string totalAmount { get; set; }

  }
}
```

This is my post method

```
public ActionResult PlaceOrder(Products products, ConfirmOrder confirmOrder, Checkout orderlist)
{
  var userid = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
  orderlist.userId = userid;
  orderlist.productlist.productId = products.productId;
  HttpResponseMessage response = GlobalVariables.webApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync("confirmVoucherPayment", orderlist).Result;
}
```

I am able to access the userId by when I pass the productid then it throws an error stating

> "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*" "*.Checkout.productlist.get returned null.*" I want to pass below JSON object to confirm the order

```
{"userId":1,"productList":[{"productId":7,"totalAmount":"236.25","quantity":2},{"productId":19,"totalAmount":"400","quantity":1}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

productlist should be initialized before using. e.g. in your class change

```
public productList productlist { get; set; }
```

to

```
public productList productlist = new productList() { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json has product list as an array. Your c# class should be:

```
public class Checkout { 

    public string userId { get; set; }

    public productList[] productlist { get; set; }

    public class productList
    {
        public int productId { get; set; }

        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public string totalAmount { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you re-do your classes first.

try this

```
  public class ProductList
 {
public int productId { get; set; }
public string totalAmount { get; set; }
public int quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Checkout
{
public int userId { get; set; }
public List<ProductList> productList { get; set; }
}
```

you must also always check (watch) the value of your `orderlist` if you pass the json you provided and use the class format suggested, the `orderlist` obj will be parsed correctly